# SignatureDoesNotMatch error from S3 putObject

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS Javascript SDK to put files to my S3. The following code is intended to upload a user avatar to the S3. I'm hardcoding the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey for now, and taking the file and key for uploading from a web form.

```
 document.getElementById("upload-button").onclick = function() {
     const key = document.getElementById("key-text").value;
     var file = document.getElementById("file-chooser").files[0];

     const S3 = new AWS.S3({
      signatureVersion: "v4",
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY_ID',
      secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
      region: 'us-west-2'
    })

      S3.putObject({
        Key: key,
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
        Body: file,
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          alert("Error: " + err);
        } else {
          alert("Upload successful: " + data);
        }
      })
  }
 document.getElementById("upload-button").onclick = function() {
     const key = document.getElementById("key-text").value;
     var file = document.getElementById("file-chooser").files[0];

     const S3 = new AWS.S3({
      signatureVersion: "v4",
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY_ID',
      secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
      region: 'us-west-2'
    })

      S3.putObject({
        Key: key,
        Bucket: 'ilarp-data-prod-1',
        Body: file,
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          alert("Error: " + err);
        } else {
          alert("Upload successful: " + data);
        }
      })
  }
```

The code above gives me an error return of SignatureDoesNotMatch I'm mystified by that, since I thought I was letting the API do the signing, and earlier versions of this (which I unfortunately cannot reproduce) did not give me this error.

Comment: make sure the time sync is proper on the server.

Comment: Signing of signed URLs is done entirely locally, in this case in the browser (not recommended), and not by a service API.  The service is not aware of the signed URL until you use it.  Can you show us the *entire* error output from S3?

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I've since realized that my test was mismatching an accessKeyId and secretAccessKey, and that was why it was telling me that the signature did not match.  Because it didn't.  In spite of checking the strings multiple times for just this issue, I still missed it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, I'm signing the URLs in the browser, that's what the API does.  It turns out that the IAM users have VERY limited permissions, which is why I'm willing to expose their credentials to a browser.  I'm sure there are other ways to do this...

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that this was pilot error.  I was mismatching the ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.  Even though I checked this very thing a dozen times, I still got it wrong.  Sorry about that.  If you come here wondering about this, know that every programmer makes a dumb mistake every once in a while.

Comment: I had changed the access key and when pasting the secret part, it pasted in half up to the special character used in the previous secret. Spent at least an hour trying to figure out why this error is happening, it must be one of the least descriptive errors that I have come across as it seems to point to something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by the filename/key I was using starting with `/`. By simply removing the proceeding forward slash it solved the issue I was encountering.

For example:

This snippet causes the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error:

```js
await storage.putObject({
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Key: `/${req.params.customer}/uploads/${filename}`,
    Body: fileContent,
});
```

Whereas this snippet does not cause the error:

```js
await storage.putObject({
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Key: `${req.params.customer}/uploads/${filename}`,
    Body: fileContent,
});
```